# Multiple choice variable with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think I do not see something quite obvious here. I have a multiple choice question ([date here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109495328/data.ods)) with 5 answer categories.

I want to melt all 5 variables together to have one graph with ggplot2. Here is my code:

```
mydata <- data.frame(data$Q006_01, data$Q006_02, data$Q006_03, data$Q006_04, data$Q006_05) # multiple choice question
md <- melt(mydata, id=c("data.Q006_01", "data.Q006_02", "data.Q006_03", "data.Q006_04", "data.Q006_05"))
luogo_lavoro <- factor(md[,1]) # error here?
ggplot(data, aes(x=luogo_lavoro)) + geom_histogram() + xlab("") + ylab("Number of participants") + ggtitle("If you had to choose now, where would you be willing to accept a job?") + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"), axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black")) + scale_x_discrete(labels=str_wrap(c("in the district I live in", "in another district as long as reachable within a dayride", "in the north of Italy", "in the rest of Italy", "abroad", "NA"), width=30)) + ggsave((filename="luogo_lavoro.pdf"), scale = 1, width = par("din")[1], height = par("din")[2], units = c("in", "cm", "mm"), dpi = 300, limitsize = TRUE)
```

What do I wrong here?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible, we do not have `rawdata`. Have a look at `dput` to provide the data.

Comment: Data is provided via the link above.

Comment: Downloading an `ods` file, dumping it to `csv` and reading the result into R is too much work for me. You want us to help you out, it is in your best interest to make it as easy as possible.

Comment: Will do it next time. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Your data example is gone. Can you please add it to the question itself if you still have it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(stringr)
data <- data.frame(id=1:nrow(data),data)
md <- melt(data,id="id")
ggplot(subset(md,value & !is.na(value)), aes(x=variable)) + 
  geom_histogram(colour="grey50",fill="lightgreen") + xlab("") + ylab("Number of participants") + 
  ggtitle("If you had to choose now, where would you be willing to accept a job?") + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black")) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=str_wrap(c("in the district I live in", 
                                     "in another district as long as reachable within a dayride", 
                                     "in the north of Italy", "in the rest of Italy", "abroad", "NA"), width=30)) +
  coord_flip()+
  ggsave((filename="luogo_lavoro.pdf"), scale = 1, width = par("din")[1], height = par("din")[2], 
         units = c("in", "cm", "mm"), dpi = 300, limitsize = TRUE)
```

In `melt(...)`, the `id=...` argument must specify a column that distinguishes between the different rows (equivalent to rownames). So I added an id column to data and melted on that. Now `md` has three columns: `id`, `variable`, and `value`. `variable` contains what used to be the column names, so `Q006_01`, etc., and `value` contains `T` or `F` depending on the response. `value` can also contain `NA` if there was no answer.

So in the call to `ggplot(...)` we use the subset of md where the response (`value`) was TRUE, and not `NA`. Doing this, `geom_hist(...)` counts the number of `TRUEs`. I included `coord_flip()` at the end so that the labels are more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pass `md` to `ggplot` in stead of `rawdata`. In addition, it is best to make `luogo_lavoro` part of `md`:

```
md$luogo_lavoro <- factor(md[,1])
```